# IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class expecting View State but received

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I'm getting crashes on crashlytics. Couldn't figure the problem and line of exception.

I have coordinatorlayout having id rootCoordinator. On button, showing bottomsheet dialog.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$SavedState instead. This usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/rootCoordinator. Make sure other views do not use the same id.
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2420)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

Bottomsheet:

```
 View bottomSheetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.common_login_bottom_sheet, rootCoordinator, false);
            gotoLoginBtn = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.gotoLoginBtn);
            closeBottomSheet = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.closeBottomSheet);
            gotoLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
//                if (bottom_sheet    !=  null && bottomSheetBehavior.getState()!=BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN){
                    HelperMethods.gotoRegister(NewProductDetailActivity.this, "");
//                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
//
//                }
                }
            });
```

Comment: replace id `rootCoordinator` with some thing else, It is being used multiple times

Comment: Post your XML and java file where you are using coordinatorlayout.

Comment: @Redman updated the question

Comment: @AskQ change id `rootCoordinator` to `rootCoordinator1` or something else